# Git Bash error: Cannot find module

Tags: bash, git-bash

I have started using Git Bash recently and I'm trying to figure out how to resolve this error:

Whenever I use commands like `atom .` or `learnyounode` (from http://nodeschool.io/#workshoppers), I get the following error:

[image]

I have a feeling it's because it's saying:

> Cannot find module 'C:**/c/**Users'

but I don't know how to resolve the problem itself.

Comment: Quick question did you do a global install of the package ? i.e                                      $ npm install -g learnyounode                                                                  will work on linux not sure how the global install works on windows

Comment: Yes, I used a global install, and the operating system I'm on is Windows 10.